# Bootstrap 3: Centering an image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLzah1x4/) with full code example.

I couldn't figure out how to upload my `placeholder.png` image and so it appears broken, but nevertheless, I am trying to figure out how to get it centered underneath the `<h3>` tag. My attempt to center it:

```
<image src="placeholder.png" style="text-align: center;" />
```

...isn't working for some reason. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class `text-center` to parent container and remove `style="text-align: center;"` from image, it's not needed:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    ...
    <img src="placeholder.png" />
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kLzah1x4/1/

Answer (score 1):

here you go - easy way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kLzah1x4/2/

```
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">    
      <img src="placeholder.png"/>
    </h3>
```

Comment: @smeeb did you solve your problem? let me know if need anything else.